# Not able to share a link through Facebook sharer

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-sharer

I am using Facebook Share in my site, I am able to share a Link "on your own wall" / "on friends wall" but Not able to share as "In a private message". I am getting an error as "The attachment could not be found" while I am sharing as "In a private message".

[image]

I am calling facebook sharer as like below :

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<"url">&t=<"text">

OR

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<"url"> , In both cases I am getting same error.

Please let me know if I am doing any thing wrong.

Thanks,
Ranjith

Comment: This issue is resolved, when I tested with production urls, if we test with QA url's it is giving that error.

Comment: did you use a port other than 80 ?